# The conditional expected value of Brownian motion $B(t)$ given $B(s)$, $s\leq t$, as well as $B(1)$

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

I am trying to calculate the expected value of the increment of Brownian motion $B(t+h)-B(t)$ given the enriched filtration generated by both $B(s)$,$s\leq t$, as well as $B(1)$.

Now as $B(t)$ is measurable with respect to this filtration obviously I can take that out of the expectation. What I'm having trouble figuring out is calculating the expected value of $B(t+h)$ given both its past as well as $B(1)$.

Any help appreciated. I have the formula

$\mathbb{E}[X|Y] = (\mathbb{E}[XY]/\mathbb{E}[Y^2])\cdot Y$ but I haven't been able to apply it successfully.

Comment: If $t\ge 1$, then $B(t+h)-B(B)\sim N(0,h)$. If $t<1$ and $t+h\ge 1$, $B(t+h)-B(t)\sim N(B(1)-B(t),t+h-1)$. If $t<1$ and $t+h<1$, $B(t+h)-B(t)$ is a scaled Brownian bridge plus a linear function.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified. h is small, so we may assume $t+h < 1$. That said, I don't understand how you obtain $B(t+h) - B(t)$ is a Brownian bridge plus a linear function. How would I explicitly derive the conditional expectation?

Comment: Let $f(h)$ be a linear function s.t. $f(0)=0$ and $f(1-t)=B(1)-B(t)$. Then $BB(h)=B(t+h)-B(t)-f(h)$ is a (scaled) Brownian bridge on $[0,1-t]$ with $BB(0)=BB(1-t)=0$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge#General_case